# OpenStack Nova and Oslo error

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I have installed OpenStack with devstack scripts in a two-node configuration, i.e. a controller/network node and a separate compute node. Everything seems have started properly, I see the services running on the nodes (if connect to screen sessions). However when trying to start an instance via dashboard, it fails with the following in the logs:

```
ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.common [req-892e7b17-49dc-4ce5-a193-ceaf547c97eb admin demo]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 137, in _dispatch_and_reply incoming.message))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 180, in _dispatch
    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 126, in _do_dispatch
    result = getattr(endpoint, method)(ctxt, **new_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/server.py", line 139, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/scheduler/manager.py", line 175, in select_destinations
    filter_properties)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/scheduler/filter_scheduler.py", line 147, in select_destinations
    filter_properties)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/scheduler/filter_scheduler.py", line 276, in _schedule
    filter_properties, index=num)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/scheduler/host_manager.py", line 359, in get_filtered_hosts
    filter_classes = self._choose_host_filters(filter_class_names)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/scheduler/host_manager.py", line 309, in _choose_host_filters
    raise exception.SchedulerHostFilterNotFound(filter_name=msg)
SchedulerHostFilterNotFound: Scheduler Host Filter  could not be found.
```

If somebody faced this issue before, could you explain how to fix it?

Comment: when you are launching an instance through dashboard, does Availability Zone shows 'Nova' ?